# How to configure Oracle 11g to launch sqlplus?

Tags: oracle11g, root, sqlplus

On a RedHat 6 server, a third party application requires to be root to run and needs access to sqlplus. I have a running database, I can run sqlplus as user 'oracle'. When logged in as user root, 'sqlplus usr/pwd@dbname' works as expected. The trouble is that this agent needs to run sqlplus with no parameters and it always returns ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied.

I've read a dozen times that enabling root to launch Oracle is a security issue but I really have no other choice.

Running Oracle 11.2.0.1.0.

Any help will be much appreciated as I've googled for 2 days with no success.

Comment: You haven't said what you've tried so this could get repetitive. Presumably you have the environment variables (`ORACLE_HOME`, `TNS_ADMIN`, `ORACLE_SID`...) set up properly, or I think you'd see different errors. Are you using the full Oracle install, and is there anything odd about the permissions in your `ORACLE_HOME`? I would suggest you have a separate installation of the instant client for `root` to use to keep as much separation as possible - is that feasible?

Comment: I have the exact same environment variable for root than for the oracle user. Yes, its a standard Enterprise Oracle installation. I checked the file permissions and ownership with another server that runs as expected but couldn't find a difference and so I suspect it's related to a configuration somewhere. Unfortunately, installing a separate client for root is not possible in this context. I feel this is a problem with the listener configuration, much more than the database. Thanks for your investigations, so far.

Comment: Yes, I'm just launching sqlplus and rely on ORACLE_SID. I've not configured any wallet, maybe is there a default config? The system that works right is using Oracle 11.1.0.6 rather than 11.2.0.1 on the other one. TWO_TASK is not set on either systems. Couldn't find any difference comparing dirs on both systems. I haven't told it yet but from user root, 'tnsping dbname' answers correctly! I'm puzzled!

Comment: The only way I know for this to happen - for remote connections to work (`tnsping dbname` and connecting `@dname`) but for local connections to get that error is through permissions; specifically when `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/oracle` isn't world-executable. But that's one of the first things Google suggests, and you've sad the permissions match a working server. Can you confirm that specific flag though? And is `root` in the `dba` group on the working server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/net12500.htm#ORA-12546), ORA_12546 is:

> **ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied**
>   **Cause:** User has insufficient privileges to perform the requested operation.
>   **Action:** Acquire necessary privileges and try again.

Which isn't entirely helpful, but various forum and blog posts (way too many to link to, Googling for the error shows a lot of similar advice) mention permissions on a particular part of the installation, `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/oracle`, which is a crucial and central part of most of the services.

Normally the permissions on that file would be `-rws-r-s--x`, with the file owned by `oracle:dba`, and this error can occur when the word-writable flag - the final `x` in that pattern - is not set. Anyone in the `dba` group will still be able to execute it, but those outside will not.

Your listener seems to be fine as you can connect remotely, by specifying `@dbname` in the connect string. The listener runs as `oracle` (usually, could be `grid` with HA, RAC or ASM) so it is in the `dba` group and can happily hand-off connections to an instance of the `oracle` executable.

When you connect without going via the listener, you have to be able to execute that file yourself. It appears that `root` cannot execute it (or possibly some other file, but this is usually the culprit, apparently), which implies the world-writable bit is indeed not set.

As far as I can see you have three options:

- set the world-writable bit, with `chmod o+x $ORACLE_HOME/bin/oracle`; but that opens up the permissions for everyone, and presumably they've been restricted for a reason;
- add `root` to the `dba` group, via `usermod` or in the `/etc/group`; which potentially weakens security as well;
- use SQL*Net even when you don't specify `@dbname` in the connect string, by adding `export TWO_TASK=dbname` to the `root` environment.

You said you don't have this problem on another server, and that the file permissions are the same; in which case `root` might be in the `dba` group on that box. But I think the third option seems the simplest and safest. There is a fourth option I suppose, to install a separate [instant client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html), but you'd have to set `TWO_TASK` anyway and go over SQL*Net, and you've already ruled that out.

I won't dwell on whether it's a good idea to run `sqlplus` (or indeed the application that needs it) as `root`, but will just mention that you'd could potentially have a script or function called `sqlplus` that switches to a less privileged account via `su` to run the real executable, and that might be transparent to the application. Unless you switch to the `oracle` account though, which is also not a good idea, you'd have the same  permission issue and options.

Comment: This is what I call a very clear explanation. I first tried the TWO_TASK setting and it now works perfectly. By the way, I wanted to check the permissions on oracle bin and they are well -rws-r-s--x. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help! My reputation isn't high enough to award you with a point, or I would give it gratefully.

Comment: @PierreVn - glad that works; possibly a directory in the path that makes up `$ORACLE_HOME/bin` has permissions 750 (`drwx-rx---`), but not sure if you get exactly that error. Also possible there is an access control list. All a bit irrelevant as `TWO_TASK` works, but always interesting to know what is wrong, not just how to work around it.

Comment: I think I deserve a pair of swipes: I did check the permissions on sub-directories except /home/oracle (Oracle installed underneath), which was 700! I chmod-ed it to 755, removed the TWO_TASK in the shell session, tried sqlplus again and guess what: it also works. Shame on me!