# How to start sqlplus (Oracle 12C) in linux?

Tags: linux, sqlplus, oracle12c

I can open Enterprise Manager on my browser by `https://localhost:port` but when I try to open sqlplus on terminal and login, it prompts me with this error:

```
ERROR:
ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied
```

How can I connect? I can connect on my browser with password that I entered during my installation but sqlplus is not accepting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure Oracle 11g to launch sqlplus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875191/how-to-configure-oracle-11g-to-launch-sqlplus)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post more information, like the exact command that you tried?

Is the listener started? Check with lsnrctl status it should give you something like this:

[oracle@oraclese ~]$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 11-AUG-2016 05:36:10

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oraclese)(PORT=1555)))

### STATUS of the LISTENER

Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                10-AUG-2016 15:39:20
Uptime                    0 days 13 hr. 56 min. 55 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /home/oracle/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/oraclese/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oraclese)(PORT=1555)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=oraclese)(PORT=5555))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/admin/ytmdb/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "pdytm1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ytmdb", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ytmdb" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ytmdb", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ytmdbXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ytmdb", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully